# Excel VBA: passing arguments

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am working on some Excel functionality using VB - but I am getting stuck at some examples.
Current version is Excel 2007, using a blank Workbook; I've added in a module and trying a function like the following:

```
Function Addtwo(a, b)
  Addtwo = a + b
End Function
```

However, I get the error #VALUE! in my cell, when doing Addtwo(5,5). When trying to do Addtwo(B2,B3), Excel tells me my formula is wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pasted code is okay and works in my Excel 2007.

The only possible problems I can think of:

- You forgot to use the equal sign: `Addtwo(5,5)` instead of `=Addtwo(5,5)`
- Your language settings require a semicolon instead of a comma in the formula, i.e. `=Addtwo(5;5)` (in the worksheet formula only, not in the VBA code)

Comment: Indeed, it is the language setting! Is the semi-colon friendly though to use in other Excel languages?